# using @ElementCollection join with non primary key

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two simple tables and an entity:

```
CREATE TABLE student(
id not null auto_increment,
name varchar(30) not null,
student_behaviour varchar(30) not null,
primary key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE student_uniform(
id not null auto_increment,
student_name varchar(30) not null,
uniform varchar(30) not null,
primary key(id)
);

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String studentName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StudentBehaviour;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @CollectionTable(name="student_uniform",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_name")
    @Column(name="uniform")
    private Set<String> studentUniforms;
    //getters and setters avoided
```

(A student can have more than one uniform)
I would like to retrieve the student using a JPA repo:

```
Student findByName(String name);
```

The issue I am having is that to extract the list of uniforms, the columns compared are the student.id with student_uniform.student_name which results in an empty list for the studentUniforms attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need this mapping instead:

```
@CollectionTable(name="student_uniform",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
```